# tensorflow model not updating weights

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, generative-adversarial-network

I have a model that is training (it goes through steps and epochs and evaluate losses) but weights are not training.

I trying to train a discriminator that would distinguish whether the image is synthetic or real. It's part of GANs model, I'm trying to build.

Basic structure is as followed:
[image: model structure]

I have two inputs:
1. image (could be real or synthetic) 2. labels (0 for real, 1 for synthetic)

Source Estimator is where I extract features from images. I had already trained the model and restored the weights and biases. These layers are frozen (not trainable).

```
def SourceEstimator(eye, name, trainable = True):
  # source estimator and target representer shares the same structure.
  # SE is not trainable, while TR is.
  net = tf.layers.conv2d(eye, 32, 3, (1,1), padding='same', activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu, trainable=trainable, name=name+'_conv2d_1')
  net = tf.layers.conv2d(net, 32, 3, (1,1), padding='same', activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu, trainable=trainable, name=name+'_conv2d_2')
  net = tf.layers.conv2d(net, 64, 3, (1,1), padding='same', activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu, trainable=trainable, name=name+'_conv2d_3')
  c3 = net
  net = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(net, 3, (2,2), padding='same', name=name+'_maxpool_4')
  net = tf.layers.conv2d(net, 80, 3, (1,1), padding='same', activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu, trainable=trainable, name=name+'_conv2d_5')
  net = tf.layers.conv2d(net, 192, 3, (1,1), padding='same', activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu, trainable=trainable, name=name+'_conv2d_6')
  c5 = net
  return (c3, c5)
```

Discriminator is as followed:

```
def DiscriminatorModel(features, reuse=False):
  with tf.variable_scope('discriminator', reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE):
    net = tf.layers.conv2d(features, 64, 3, 2, padding='same', kernel_initializer='truncated_normal', activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu, trainable=True, name='discriminator_c1')
    net = tf.layers.conv2d(net, 128, 3, 2, padding='same', kernel_initializer='truncated_normal', activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu, trainable=True, name='discriminator_c2')
    net = tf.layers.conv2d(net, 256, 3, 2, padding='same', kernel_initializer='truncated_normal', activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu, trainable=True, name='discriminator_c3')

    net = tf.contrib.layers.flatten(net)
    net = tf.layers.dense(net, units=1, activation=tf.nn.softmax, name='descriminator_out', trainable=True)
    return net
```

Input goes to SourceEstimator model and extracts features (c3,c5).

Then c3 and c5 is concatenated along the channel axis and passed to discriminator model.

```
c3, c5 = CommonModel(self.left_eye, 'el', trainable=False)
c5 = tf.image.resize_images(c5, size=(self.config.img_size,self.config.img_size))
features = tf.concat([c3, c5], axis=3)
##---------------------------------------- DISCRIMINATOR ------------------------------------------##
with tf.variable_scope('discriminator'):
    logit = DiscriminatorModel(features)
```

Finally losses and train_ops

```
##---------------------------------------- LOSSES ------------------------------------------##
with tf.variable_scope("discriminator_losses"):
  self.loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logit, labels=self.label))

##---------------------------------------- TRAIN ------------------------------------------##
# optimizers
update_ops = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)
with tf.control_dependencies(update_ops):
    disc_optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate = learning_rate)
    self.disc_op = disc_optimizer.minimize(self.loss, global_step=self.global_step_tensor, name='disc_op')
```

Train steps and epochs. I'm using 32 batch size. And data generator class to get the image each step.

```
def train_epoch(self):
    num_iter_per_epoch = self.train_data.get_size() // self.config.get('batch_size')
    loop = tqdm(range(num_iter_per_epoch))
    for i in loop:
        dloss = self.train_step(i)
        loop.set_postfix(loss='{:05.3f}'.format(dloss))

def train_step(self, i):
    el, label = self.train_data.get_batch(i)

    ## ------------------- train discriminator -------------------##
    feed_dict = {
            self.model.left_eye: el,
            self.model.label: label
    }
    _, dloss = self.sess.run([self.model.disc_op, self.model.loss], feed_dict=feed_dict)
    return dloss
```

While the model is going through steps and epochs, weight remains unchanged.

Loss fluctuates during the training steps, but loss for every epoch is the same. For example, if I don't shuffle the dataset each epoch, loss on the graph will follow the same pattern each epoch.

Which I think means the model recognizes the different losses, but is not updating parameters according to the losses.

Here are few other things I tried and did not help:

1. tried small and big learning rate (0.1 and 1e-8)
2. tried with SourceEstimator layers trainable==True
3. flipped labels (0 == synthetic, 1 == real)
4. increased kernel sizes and filter sizes in discriminator.

I've been stuck on this problem for a while now, I really need some insights. Thanks in advance.

------EDIT 1-----

```
def initialize_uninitialized(sess):
    global_vars = tf.global_variables()
    is_initialized= sess.run([tf.is_variable_initialized(var) for var in global_vars])
    not_initialized_vars = [v for (v, f) in zip(global_vars, is_initialized) if not f]

    # for var in not_initialized_vars: # only for testing
    #    print(var.name)

    if len(not_initialized_vars):
        sess.run(tf.variables_initializer(not_initialized_vars))

self.sess = tf.Session()
## inbetween here I create data generator, model and restore pretrained model.
self.initilize_uninitialized(self.sess) 

for current_epoch in range(self.model.current_epoch_tensor.eval(self.sess), self.config.num_epochs, 1)
    self.train_epoch() # included above
    self.sess.run(self.model.increment_current_epoch_tensor)
```

Answer (score 1):

I can see that you are calling minimize as well as loss function in session.run(). You should only call minimize() function. i.e. only self.model.disc_op which will internally call loss function.
Also, I cannot see your session initialization call anywhere. See to it that it is getting called only once.

Looking at your updated code, I can see that you are equating tf.is_variable_initialized() call to is_not_initialized. Thus, it is initializing those variables which are already initialized.

Comment: You are right I didn't include session initialization. Because part of the model is restored from pretrained model. I had to create custom initialization function to initialize only uninitialized variables. Didn't want to overwhelm with unnecessary codes.
Also I tried your suggestion of calling only the minimize function. Unfortunately didn't help. I was calling loss function to do simple evaluation each epoch and I don't think that was the problem :(

Comment: included session initialization to the post!

Comment: Looking at your updated code, I can see that you are equating tf.is_variable_initialized() call to is_not_initialized. Thus, it is initializing those variables which are already initialized.

Comment: Thank you, I should fix that, that is poor naming. However, in the following line, when getting not_initialized_vars, it had been compensated for. not_initialized_vars = [v for (v, f) in zip(global_vars, is_not_initialized) if not f]

Comment: Can you also include the code where you are getting logits?

Answer (score 1):

I never managed to find out what was wrong with the code.

My colleague suggested trying the same model in a different isolated environment, so I rewrote the code using Keras Library.

And now it's working. :/

We still don't know what exactly was wrong with the code above - I didn't change anything. I even used the same code for weight transferring and variable initialization.

If anyone ever faces similar problem, I would suggest trying the same model in a different environment.

Or if anyone knows what was wrong with the code above please share!

Comment: Have you checked the difference between 2 environments? Version of Python, tensorflow and whether using under anaconda and which version of anaconda?

Comment: I'll have to check for exact version of python, tensorflow, and keras I was using, but I did use the same virtual environment. python==3.6.6 / tensorflow==1.10.0 / keras==2.2.4